# How to set a static file on a cherrypy configuration file?

Tags: configuration, static, cherrypy

I have a web application on CherryPy. I'm trying to configure a css file to use over all application but I can't. This is my conf file:

```
[global]
server.socket_host = "127.0.0.1"
server.socket_port = 8090
server.thread_pool = 10
server.logToScreen = 0

[/main.css]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "E:\apyb\main.css"
```

If I set config on code instead on a file it works fine:

```
conf = {
    '/main.css': {
    'tools.staticfile.on': True,
    'tools.staticfile.filename': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'main.css'),
    }
}
```

How can I set up the path file?

I'm using Cherrypy 3.1.2 over Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CherryPy configuration files use Python syntax for values. So just like in Python, when you enter a string with backslashes, it may interpret them as control characters:

```
>>> "E:\apyb\main.css"
'E:\x07pyb\\main.css'
>>> print "E:\apyb\main.css"
E:pyb\main.css
```

The solution is to double the slashes:

```
>>> "E:\\apyb\\main.css"
'E:\\apyb\\main.css'
>>> print "E:\\apyb\\main.css"
E:\apyb\main.css
```

Do the same in your config file:

```
[/main.css]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "E:\\apyb\\main.css"
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The server returned a 404 to path http://127.0.0.1:8090/main.css

Comment: Are you passing the config file to `quickstart()`? or `tree.mount()`?

Comment: You have reason. I couldn't check this before but it works and very fine. Thank you so much.